# Is it correct? "Fixing this issue will take 2~3 days"

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

"Fixing this issue will take 2~3 days"

Is the above sentence structure correct? In fact, I want to express: I will fix this issue. And, if I successfully fix this issue, need to 2-3 days.

In fact, I want to let "Fixing this issue" as a subject, then "will take" as a a predicate. Is this writing Ok?

Comment: "Fixing this issue will take 2~3 days" is grammatical. The *gerund* forms (verbal nouns) of verbs will act as nouns.

Comment: @mahmudkoya Thanks for your reply.  Your explanations are wonderful.

Comment: Yes, it's fine, but I'd use *2-3* instead of *2~3*, as it is more common.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for your correction. I'll keep it(2-3) in mind. And, about "2-3", may I say that "two to three" ?

Comment: @Drew It may be more common, but it is no more proper. Use _2–3_ instead of _2-3_. The former means _two to three_, the latter means a _two-three_, whatever that is (an exaggerated _one-two_, perhaps?). Or even better, “two to three days”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I very appreciate that you explain 2–3 in more detail.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I would say "two **or** three", since those are the only options.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Yes, an en dash; agreed. And yes to HotLicks: "two or three", if there are only two possible values.

Comment: Sometimes ~ 2-3 or something similar is used to indicate "approximately 2-3 days"  I've never seen 2~3, but if I did, I would assume it meant the same thing.  Also, it isn't a binary choice, it is an approximate range.

Comment: 2~3 is fine for informal use, but I've never seen it used like that and I would consider it an error

Comment: You **could** say *~2 to 3 days, but I think it's a little too clever. It comes from mathematics and means an approximation

Comment: From abstractmath.org: The symbol "~" is pronounced "tilde" (till-day or till-dee), or informally "twiddle" or "squiggle".
The tilde may be placed on top of a variable, for example "x~x~" with several possible meanings.
Before a number the tilde is used to mean "approximately". "~42" means "approximately 42".
∼,≈,≃,≅∼,≈,≃,≅ are all used to denote binary relations. More about this below.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence, "Fixing this issue will take 2-3 days" is grammatically correct. However, you would replace the tilde (~) with a hyphen (-).